# Automatic line break in div

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to display pictures in a special div. 
So now it looks like this : [image]

So as you can see the green divs are out of there parent div (black one)

It's built like this :

```
<div class="photoView center">
    <div class="grid">
        <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]" class="groupPhoto">
            <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]" class="col-1-4 photoSimple" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.photoPrincipal {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.photoView {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.photoSimple {
  width: 130px;
  height:75px;
  background-color: green;
  margin:10px;
  border: 2px dotted white;
  display:block;
}
```

**EDIT**
I fogot to mention that I use SimpleGrid, which is a "CSS library" which delivers css for grid. now it works with this : http://jsfiddle.net/jmsqskyn/

So basically I just want 4 green divs per line. But it continues.

I tried to apply a `display:block`but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you please post your css?

Comment: Because your `.photoView` is of fixed size (600x300) and without `overflow` set which, becomes `visible` by default. Change the height to auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

- I added a float:left to .photoSimple, so we have to clear the parent container (.photoView).
- You can also use a clearfix in .photoView, but overflow:hidden, will do the trick for now.
- Check this out: http://www.adamkaplan.me/css-clearfix/.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jmsqskyn/

Demo using clearfix: http://jsfiddle.net/jmsqskyn/1/

```
.photoView{
    overflow:hidden; /* Add */
    width: 600px;
    /* height: 300px; */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.photoSimple{
    width: 125px;
    height:75px;
    background-color: green;
    margin:10px;
    border: 2px dotted white;
    display:block;
    float:left; /* Add */
}
```

Comment: For me the rest gets hidden and there is nos "line break"

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa I don't understand what you are getting. What gets hidden? Have you looked at the Demo? I just tested the demo in IE, Safari, Firefox and Chrome and it works fine.

Comment: You see my picture in my first post ? So I get this BUT the green divs are cut when it overflows

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa, This is with the clearfix : http://jsfiddle.net/jmsqskyn/1/

Answer (score 1):

Switch your css to `display:inline-block` for your DIVs.

So, since your edit, change it to:

```
.photoSimple {
  width: 130px;
  height:75px;
  background-color: green;
  margin:10px;
  border: 2px dotted white;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

And if you can't use `display:inline-block;` try switching it for `float:left;`.

Comment: style="display:inline-block;

Comment: Are you sure?  It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/3t09aqrv/

In your CSS for `.photoSimple`, change it to `display:inline-block;`

Comment: What do you mean you think?  It either works or it doesn't.  Here's an alternate version that uses `float:left`.  http://jsfiddle.net/sx5dg4oe/ I have tested this version and the `display:inline-block` version and they *both* work in IE9+, FF and Chrome.  I need more info from you to determine the real issue here, otherwise it seems fine in the JSFiddles.

Comment: In the JSFiddle it doesn't fit in the black box there are only three green boxes

Comment: This : http://jsfiddle.net/jmsqskyn/ works perfectly on fiddle but I cannot reproduce it on my website

Comment: Something on your website is over-riding the float value then.  Try this one to prove it, I added `float:left!important;` to force a left float: http://jsfiddle.net/jmsqskyn/3/ Wait, did you already accept another answer, why are you commenting here?